# in wordpress, is there a way to hook a function/method to an action thats being being added/registered in a different location/file

Tags: wordpress, file, callback, action, hook

For my plugin, i have my directory structure as follows:

```
-My-Plugin
  - My-Plugin.php
  - My-Plugin-actions.php
  - My-Plugin-classes.php
  - My-Plugin-functions.php
```

this is what My-Plugin.php file contains:

```
<?php
  require_once( WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/My-Plugin/My-Plugin-actions.php' );
  require_once( WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/My-Plugin/My-Plugin-classes.php' );
  require_once( WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/My-Plugin/My-Plugin-functions.php' );
?>
```

And My-Plugin-actions.php contain actions that call functions/methods in My-Plugin-classes.php and My-Plugin-functions.php:

```
<?php
  add_action("action_function","some_function_in_functions_file");
  add_action("action_method","some_method_in_classes_file");
?>
```

So how can i call the functions and methods that are defined in different files from where their actions are registered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP hits each of those require() lines and then parses the file you're referencing. But you have actions loading first. So when PHP goes to execute that code, those functions do not exist because it hasn't gotten to the line where your functions file is parsed.

So you need to have your actions file be called after your functions have been called.

Comment: You're welcome. If this was all one file you could probably define the functions where ever and it would work, but not separate files.